# How to delete a file with a specific word in the filename in python

Tags: python

To better illustrate what I'm trying to do, I download a iTunes file in m4a but it's encrypted by widevine so I decrypt it to get a DRM free m4a file

so in the download folder there is:

- 8 - Bring Me The Horizon - Run.m4a
- 8 - Bring Me The Horizon - Run_encrypted.m4a

And my question is : is there a sort of algorithm who can filter files in my download folder with the word "encrypted" and delete them?

Comment: Unless you specifically need this in Python, you could do this with a shell command - `rm *_encrypted.m4a`. Otherwise, in Python you can just `glob` with `Pathlib` and find the files with the `_encrypted` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using glob.

```
import glob
import os

# path to search file
path = 'path_to_folder/*encrypted.m4a'
for file_path in glob.glob(path, recursive=True):
    print(file_path)
    os.remove(file_path)
```